# Activate multiple buttons when pressing one

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm doing my first GUI on Tkinter and I'm having some issues getting more than one button to activate after clicking one.

I have the button `Main` that's always active by default, and once it's pressed it should activate `Button1, Button2, Button3, Button5 and Button6` that are disabled by default. This is my code at the moment.

Function that activates the buttons:

```
def activateButtons():
    for i in (Button1, Button2, Button3, Button5, Button6):
        i.config(state=ENABLED)
```

Button that calls the function:

```
loadDB= tk.Button(
  root,
  width=10,
  text = "Load DB.",
  bg = "black",
  fg = "blue",
  command=lambda:[loadDBF(),activateButtons()]).pack(expand = True)
```

and the buttons:

```
Button1 = tk.Button(
  root,
  width= 15,
  text= "Button 1",
  bg="black",
  fg="blue",
  state=DISABLED).pack(expand = True)

Button2 = tk.Button(
  root,
  width= 15,
  text= "Button 2",
  bg="black",
  fg="blue",
  state=DISABLED).pack(expand = True)

Button3 = tk.Button(
  root,
  width= 15,
  text= "Button3",
  bg="black",
  fg="blue",
  state=DISABLED).pack(expand = True)

Button4 = tk.Button(
  root,
  width= 15,
  text= "Button 4",
  bg="black",
  fg="blue",
  state=DISABLED).pack(expand = True)

Button4 = tk.Button(
  root,
  width= 15,
  text= "Button 1",
  bg="black",
  fg="blue",
  state=DISABLED).pack(expand = True)

Button5 = tk.Button(
  root,
  width= 15,
  text= "Button 1",
  bg="black",
  fg="blue",
  state=DISABLED).pack(expand = True)

Button6 = tk.Button(
  root,
  width= 15,
  text= "Button 1",
  bg="black",
  fg="blue",
  state=DISABLED).pack(expand = True)
```

Any idea on how to get them to activate once I press `loadDB`?

Comment: All of your `ButtonX` variables are None - the result of `.pack()`, rather than the Buttons themselves.  This should be generating a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'` when you try to activate them - are you not seeing that?

Comment: How could I correct it? If I remove it they dissapear from the GUI

Comment: Just found a way to do it thanks to this correction, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ENABLED` with `NORMAL`.

```py
def activateButtons():
    for i in (Button1, Button2, Button3, Button5, Button6):
        i.config(state=NORMAL)
```

Comment: I got: z.config(state=NORMAL)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Comment: @theJohnLewis the function can't find your buttons then. Are you sure you have defined them with the correct scope?

Comment: It's my first time doing this so maybe not, how should they be defined?

Comment: @theJohnLewis You'll need to add more of your program to the question for that, making it easier to debug

Comment: That's pretty much all of it, the rest are functions that have nothing to do with the buttons

Comment: But where are you defining the buttons? Inside another function?

Comment: I thought that the way I wrote them was right, but I was just told that it's not.

Comment: I think I got it now